# Install Nodeclipse to Eclipse 2018-12 fails

Tags: nodeclipse

Im trying to install Nodeclipse (from https://nodeclipse.github.io/) to my Eclipse IDE (ver 2018-12) through the marketplace client but get the following error:

```
The following solutions are not available: Enide (Studio) 2015 - Node.js, JavaScript, Java and Web tools 1.0.2.
```

[image: error message from eclipse]

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Facing same issue in Eclipse Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).